# cambiar valores de impresión en input Range

Tags: html, input

Quisiera que me apoyaran a cambiar los valores numericos de impresion en un input "range"

```
<p><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
<input style="width:80%;" type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="1" step="0.02" value="0.5" 
onchange="document.getElementById('outvol').value=value" list="tickmarks">
<output id="outvol" name="outvol" for="vol">0.5</output>
</p>
</body>
<datalist id="tickmarks">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="0.1"></option>
    <option value="0.2"></option>
    <option value="0.3"></option>
    <option value="0.4"></option>
    <option value="0.5"></option>
    <option value="0.6"></option>
    <option value="0.7"></option>
    <option value="0.8"></option>
    <option value="0.9"></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
</datalist>
```

que en lugar de 0.1 me mostrara mal estado en 0.2 estado bajo y así en cada valor un  texto diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así, usando el controlador de eventos [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) de javascript:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("vol");
var output = document.getElementById("outvol");
let estado = 'estado medio';

output.innerHTML = estado;

slider.oninput = function() {
  correlacion_valores = {
    '0': 'sin estado',
    '0.1': 'mal estado',
    '0.2': 'estado bajo',
    '0.3': 'estado no tan bajo',
    '0.4': 'estado menos bajo',
    '0.5': 'estado medio',
    '0.6': 'estado medio y subiendo',
    '0.7': 'estado notable bajo',
    '0.8': 'estado notable alto',
    '0.9': 'estado superior',
    '1': 'estado máximo'
  }

  estado = correlacion_valores[this.value];
  output.innerHTML = estado;
};
```

```html
<p><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
<input style="width:80%;" type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"><br>
<output id="outvol" name="outvol" for="vol">Estado medio</output>
</p>
```